# Is there a work around Snowflake's TIMESTAMP_NTZ/TIMESTAMP_LTZ in MATLAB?

Tags: database, matlab, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I got this error when I tried to upload a table from MATLAB console to Snowflake data warehouse using the sqlwrite function.

```
ODBC Error: ODBC Driver Error: SQL compilation error:
Expression type does not match column data type, expecting TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) but got TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9) for column TIMESTAMP.
```

I tried to change the Timezone to 'local', '' and the real one and it's not working. I could change the data type of the column to TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9) but that is not what it is intended to do. Is there a work around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Jonathan! I think we need some more info. What version of Matlab are you running? And what format are the date columns in your `table` that you're trying to upload to that Snowflake timestamp column? Are they `datetime`s or `string`s or `cellstr`s or something else?

Comment: `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` means `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. Did you try removing the time zone info entirely?

Comment: The data type of the column from the MATLAB's table is a datetime. And the MATLAB version is 2020a.

Comment: Yes I tried, first without naming it, then naming it with a empty string('') and lastly with 'local' and I have the same Error.

Comment: Hmmm. Sounds like a bit of a bug to me; I'd think that a `datetime` with an empty (`''`) TimeZone would go in to a `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` just fine. How about try converting that `datetime` column to a `string` column in format `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF` using `datestr`, and try inserting that? Passing the values as string instead of datetime will probably cause the Database Toolbox to use a different code path for the variable binding. (You're using the Matlab Database Toolbox for this, right?)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Database Toolbox. I just tried to converting it in a string and it's still the same error.